# Azure Function Portal: script still exists even though it is deleted in the new deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions

This is the old project that I have deployed to Azure function:

```
<root-directory>
├── README.md
├── dist
├── bin
├── dependencies
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── sealworker
│   ├── constants
│   ├── errors
│   ├── function.json
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── interfaces
│   ├── sample.dat
│   ├── services
│   ├── utils
│   ├── sealworkerfunction.ts  // this will be removed
│   └── worker.ts   // this will be removed
└── tsconfig.json
```

After removing the files, this is the new project in local:

```
<root-directory>
├── README.md
├── ...
├── sealworker
│   ├── constants
│   ├── errors
│   ├── function.json
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── interfaces
│   ├── sample.dat
│   ├── services
│   └── utils   
└── tsconfig.json
```

And this is how I do zip deployment:

```
rm -rf dist/ && npm run-script build && zip -r azure_function.zip .  && az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g sealworkerdevda1 -n sealworkerfunction2 --src azure_function.zip


Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
{
  "active": true,
  "author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "Push-Deployer",
  "end_time": "2023-08-09T16:12:30.1188313Z",
  "id": "2a1d69d2-f3af-435c-a5e7-b2fc1b1e6c48",
  "is_readonly": true,
  "is_temp": false,
  "last_success_end_time": "2023-08-09T16:12:30.1188313Z",
  "log_url": "https://sealworkerfunction2.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
  "message": "Created via a push deployment",
  "progress": "",
  "received_time": "2023-08-09T16:12:24.3388912Z",
  "site_name": "sealworkerfunction2",
  "start_time": "2023-08-09T16:12:26.2433316Z",
  "status": 4,
  "status_text": "",
  "url": "https://sealworkerfunction2.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
}
```

I first remove the old build `dist/`, then I do build again and deploy with a zip file again.

The deployment was successful.

However, the deleted scripts still exists in Code + Test section of the azure function portal:

[image]

I can confirm that the new zip file is uploaded into the `/home/data/SitePackages` folder.

By the way, the `wwwroot` folder is like this:

```
kudu_ssh_user@6dfe9b30b25a:~/site/wwwroot$ ls -lat 
total 2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup 1445 Aug  4 13:35 .gitignore
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody nogroup    0 Aug  4 06:32 .vscode
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup  120 Aug  3 15:59 .funcignore
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody nogroup    0 Aug  3 06:33 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody nogroup    0 Aug  3 06:33 ..
kudu_ssh_user@6dfe9b30b25a:~/site/wwwroot$
```

SO Why are the removed files still showing?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Function Portal: script still exists even though it is deleted in the new deployment

I have reproduced similar situation in my environment. I have deployed an Azure function with name **“deletedfile”** and the function name is **“test”**.

I have created 2 files `test2.js` and `test3.js` and deployed. In My azure function **“deletedfile”**, **code + test** section files are visible as shown below:

[image]

But after redeploying the function after I removed the files `test2.js` and `test3.js`. However, It was not visible in my function’s **code + test** environment as shown below:

[image]

Try redeploying the Function.